# Custom scss in Storefront Shopware 6.1

Tags: shopware

I have trouble to load my scss Files for my shopware 6.1 Storefront Plugin.
It should work automatically by placing the files in the right location. But there is the correct location now in 6.1 with the changes to the directory stucture. The shopware documentation was not updated.

I tried:
`plugin-root/src/Resources/app/storfront/src/style`
and
`plugin-root/src/Resources/app/storfront/style`

But it doesn't work.

So far I load my scss with webpack import, but it only worked after changing the webpack config. So I guess this is not the recommended way.

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried the correct path? In your message is a spelling error - it's not "storfront", but "storefront".

From the official changelog.md of shopware 6.1: https://github.com/shopware/platform/blob/6.1/CHANGELOG-6.1.md

[image]

As fas as I can see, the path should be:

```
plugin/src/Resources/app/storefront/src/scss
```

The example plugin should show it too: https://github.com/shopware/swag-docs-storefront-assets/tree/master/src/Resources/app/storefront/scss

Answer (score 0):

It is scss not style, thanks, that works.